# What is the difference between const string &s and string &s?

Tags: c++, literals, string-literals

This is the code from *c++ primer*:

```
string::size_type findChar(const string &s, char c, string::size_type & occurs){
    auto ret = s.size();
    occurs = 0;
    for (decltype(ret) i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i){
        if (s[i] == c){
            if (ret == s.size())
                ret = i;
            occurs++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main () {
    string::size_type ctr;
    cout << findChar("hello, world!", 'o', ctr);
}
```

An error happened after removing `const` from `const string &s`.

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string&'} to an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'}
> cout << findChar("hello, world!", 'o', ctr);

I wonder, in this case, what behaviors of compiler does the `const` keyword change? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What error, exactly, happened?

Comment: Removing `const` means "this value can be manipulated" which may not be permitted depending on how the argument is provided.

Comment: @nathanpierson I have added it into the question.

Comment: You need to study c++ move semantics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string literal like `"hello, world!"` is not a `std::string`. So to call your function the compiler has to create a `std::string` for you. Such an object is called a *temporary*. So in the first case the compiler uses `"hello, world!"` to create a `std::string` and then *binds* that temporary string to reference parameter `s`.

However C++ has a rule that you *cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference*. But when you change `s` from `const std::string&` to `std::string&` you are asking the compiler to do exactly that. This is what the error message is telling you.

If you changed your code to this

```
string::size_type ctr;
string hello = "hello, world!";
cout << findChar(hello, 'o', ctr);
```

it will now compile even without const. The difference here is that the compiler is no longer creating a temporary `std::string` (because `hello` is already a `std::string`). So the rule about temporaries and non-const references doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a class. const char* is a pointer to memory that hopefully contains a null-terminated string. You can use std::string to pass by value and make copies without having to call functions like strcpy.

Use std::string whenever you can and the c_str() method when you need a pointer to the string, e.g., for older C libraries.

Comment: All of this is true, but it doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

In the calling code, the object passed for `s` is `"hello, world!"`, which is a string whose contents that cannot be changed. In the function `findChar` the type `const string &s` is a reference named `s` to an object of type `const string`. These two types are matched, so the compilation completes successfully.

However, a parameter `string &s` denotes a referenced named `s` to an object of type `string` - this is a mutable (changeable) string. But the passed in argument (`"hello, world!"`) is a string that cannot be changed. When this happens the compiler indicates a type mismatch error.

Comment: This is untrue. The type mismatch causes the compiler to construct a temporary, and it the rule about binding non-const references to temporaries that causes the compiler error, not the type mismatch.